# How do you create a legend for the bucket divisions in a fusion table map?

Tags: google, google-fusion-tables

I am creating a map using Google fusion tables.  I have divided the data into "buckets" using the Configure Map Styles window. Is there a way to add a legend to the map telling the readers what the colors (buckets) relate to?

Answer (score 1):

It's on the feature request list:

http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=37&q=Type%3DFeature_Request&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Stars%20Component